# How do I write to a file from different threads in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to find a way to lock writing to a file in different threads. What is the correct way to do it? I would like not to open and close the file all the time when I need to write something, because of the performance.

The code I tried is:

```
use std::{fs, mem, thread};
use std::os::unix::prelude::FileExt;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};


const COUNT: usize = 1000;


fn main() {
    let file: fs::File = fs::File::create("foo.txt").unwrap();

    let v: [u32; COUNT] = [6; COUNT];

    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    let mut threads = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..COUNT {
        let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);

        let thread = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut i = counter.lock().unwrap();

            let offset = (mem::size_of::<u32>() * (*i)) as u64;
            let bytes = unsafe { mem::transmute::<u32, [u8; 4]>(v[*i]) };
            file.write_all_at(&bytes, offset).unwrap();

            *i += 1;
        });
        threads.push(thread);
    }

    for thread in threads {
        thread.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

And it gives the error:

```
move occurs because `file` has type `std::fs::File`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

As far as I understand, the file object cannot be easily shared between the threads. I guess, I do something wrong in the whole approach regarding this issue. So what is the correct way to write into a file from different threads in Rust?

Comment: ...just make another `Arc<Mutex>` for `file` like you did for `counter`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a `Vec<u8>` then mutably borrowing the part that the thread needed, with a final `file.write_all(&vec)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap the file in an `Arc` and a `Mutex`, which will allow it to be shared between threads, and mutated by one thread at a time:

```rust
fn main() {
    let file = Arc::new(Mutex::new(File::create("foo.txt").unwrap()));

    let v: [u32; COUNT] = [6; COUNT];

    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    let mut threads = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..COUNT {
        let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
        let file = Arc::clone(&file);

        let thread = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut i = counter.lock().unwrap();
            let file = file.lock().unwrap();

            let offset = (mem::size_of::<u32>() * (*i)) as u64;
            let bytes = unsafe { mem::transmute::<u32, [u8; 4]>(v[*i]) };
            file.write_all_at(&bytes, offset).unwrap();

            *i += 1;
        });
        threads.push(thread);
    }

    for thread in threads {
        thread.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Note that the read and write methods in `std::os::unix::fs::FileExt` take an immutable reference to `self`. This means that the code above *would* compile without the `Mutex`, because concurrency is managed by the os kernel. However, the result is non-deterministic given that multiple threads might try to write to the file at the same time, which is probably not what you want.